# Payment webhooks stops working in Magento Cloud 2 with PWA frontend

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, pwa, magento-cloud

In Magento Cloud 2.4.4 with Luma I had NO problems with the Conekta Webhooks

*Conekta is a payment processing platform, like PayPal or Stripe*

**After the frontend changed to PWA, the payment webhooks stopped working.**

How to allow payment webhooks "touch Magento Backend" with a PWA frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging with postman I find that the response from my cloud server is NOT the same as my local server.

The PWA configuration returns an HTML response to Conekta Webhooks, so the information from the webhook never gets into Controller

I found the solution in the video of this master

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23N8EIb0Te8

You need to go to the Admin Page

Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web
UPWARD PWA Configuration > Front Name Allowlist

And simply write the word

> conekta

Below the word "shipping"

---

[image: PWA payment webhooks]

---

Save and clean configuration cache, and that's it. Now the payment webhooks for Conekta works again!